# Spring: Good approach to update user enitity in REST Controller?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want to update my user data in the Spring application. I create RESTful controller, but I don't know which approach is better:

1. Here it passes the entire UserPayload from the request as one parameter, but then the id from @PathVariable is completely unnecessary. Then in UserService searches for the user by id from UserPayload and I replace his data:

Controller:

```java
@PatchMapping("/users/{id}/update")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody UserPayload payload) {
        userService.updateUser(payload);
        response = new ApiResponse(true, "SUCCESSFUL_UPDATED");
        return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Service:

```java
public void updateUser(UserPayload payload) {
        User user = getUser(payload.getId());

        if (payload.getName() == null || payload.getEmail() == null) {
            throw new ServiceBadRequestException("One of parameters is null");
        }
        if (payload.getName().length() < 2) {
            throw new ServiceBadRequestException("Name cannot be smaller than 2 characters");
        }
        user.setName(payload.getName());
        user.setEmail(payload.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

2. In this case, i serach for the user in the controller and pass two parameters to the `updateUser` method, and then, as in the first case, I replace data and save.

Controller:

```java
 @PatchMapping("/users/{id}/update")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody UserPayload payload) {
        User user = userService.getUser(id);
        userService.updateUser(user, payload);
        response = new ApiResponse(true, "SUCCESSFUL_UPDATED");
        return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Service:

```java
public void updateUser(User user, UserPayload payload) {
        if (payload.getName() == null || payload.getEmail() == null) {
            throw new ServiceBadRequestException("One of parameters is null");
        }
        if (payload.getName().length() < 2) {
            throw new ServiceBadRequestException("Name cannot be smaller than 2 characters");
        }
        user.setName(payload.getName());
        user.setEmail(payload.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Which approach is more correct? Or exist a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. In general I would say you should always use the path variables to load resources to avoid making things really confusing. You also have to consider what it means to issue a patch request to a resource. It means you are applying a partial update to the object that is specified by the url. If you allow the request body to override that you can get into a scenario where the request is updating a different resource than it specified.  This could have implications for anything sitting in front of your server as well as being really confusing.

In this specific case you actually have an alternative. Use the Path variable to load the object as a ModelAttribute and then have spring auto copy the request params onto the object. You can then just call save.

```
@ModelAttribute
public User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
  return getUser(id);
}

@PatchMapping("/users/{id}/update")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    userService.save(user);
    response = new ApiResponse(true, "SUCCESSFUL_UPDATED");
    return new ResponseEntity<ApiResponse>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to do some validation for the request only. Or use versioning. Then this will bypass both. As you cannot just do the use case validation and versioning is imply ignored (i.e. detect if something has updated).

Comment: You can still do validation with the validation api. I would consider versioning to be an edge case that would require its own special approach. In either case, there is nothing preventing the service layer from still doing any of this. However, by taking this approach we eliminate the need to map from the request object to a service layer object. Whether or not that object is also your data layer object is up to your implementation.

Comment: This comment makes very little sense.  You are free to write whatever validations you want via the validation api including validations on change password requests. All multi user systems such as a restful web app are by their nature concurrent applications which is usually managed by using a Relational Database. Versioning would be an additional mechanism built into a system that is beyond the current discussion. Working on several applications I can tell you mapping layers are notorious for being slow and buggy and replacing them with systems such as this is almost always good.

Comment: I have been writing these kind of systems for 20+ years of which 16 of those with Spring. The problem of using entities directly in binding is that you end up polluting them. If you want to validate a password you endup with a second password field. Which doesn’t belong to the User. It is only valid in the usecase of changing the password. You can workaround the validation with a validation group but you still have the pollutio. Having something in a database isn’t preventing anyone from modifying the same record, unless you use locking which is slow, so you want versioning.

Comment: Your databases must grow to enormous sizes if you include versioning in every application.  It doesn't even solve the scenario you laid out. Just because your data is versioned does not prevent someone from modifying the same record concurrently. In fact it would act identically.  The only benefit versioning would bring is if you needed to see historical data.  It is true that you can easily pollute objects but it is also true that keeping the amount of mapping code to a minimum is highly beneficial.

Comment: With versioning I mean optimistic locking, which only includes a single field containing a version or timestamp. But as mentioned this question will lead to opinionated answers. Both solutions can work, there are probably even more solutions. It all depends.